# has the embed object really been depreciated, because I still use it for youtube videos

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i was doing some  iframe and object testing recently. I read and keep reading that the object has been depreciated. But last time I checked youtube doesn't make the html and php software. Anyway here is  a object in use and proves the object is still usable

```
  <object style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 820px; height: 461.25px; float:   none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;"  data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VCHH13ynHrk">
  </object>
```

So how has object been depreciated if I can still use it and get it to function any php and html platforms. I want to use it but since I keep hearing that its depreciated would like to know why.

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network doesn't consider `<object>` (and even `<embed>`) as deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Comment: Have you read the red box labeled "Deprecation Notice" on https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters ?

Comment: well the object is still displaying the youtube video on my website. Youtube videos are basically iframes. So no its not deprecated because if it were deprecated the videos wouldn't be displaying on my site. So basically the object is working on my site and its displaying the videos like its suppose to.